# Sending automatic email on specific day of the month based on day entered in a cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to send an email from Google Apps Script on a specific day of the month based on the day that a user enters into a cell on the Sheet.

Currently I use a formula as below to send emails which sends to users based on cell values:

```
function sendChangeDetailsEmail() {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("BALANCE SHEET");
  var data1 = sh.getRange("G2").getValues(); //USED AS DATA IN THE EMAIL BODY from values in the sheet
  var emailRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("BALANCE SHEET").getRange("G2"); 
  var emailRange1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("BALANCE SHEET").getRange("G1"); 
  var emailAddress = emailRange.getValues();
  var recipient = emailRange1.getValues();
  var message = 'Hello ' + recipient + "\r\r" + 'Please see the current amount that needs paying off: ' + data1 + "\r\r" + 'Many Thanks';
  var subject = 'REMINDER - Amount Due';
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
}
```

As the sheet will be used as a separate doc for each user, the user would enter the date in cell M3 on configuration for when they want the reminder to be sent, and they would only enter the date number of the month e.g. 25

Does anyone know of a way that I could do this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now got a script as below:

```js
function sendEmail() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var rng = sh.getDataRange();
  var val = rng.getDisplayValues();
  var lr = rng.getLastRow();
  var compare = sh.getRange('A9').getValue();
  var match = false;
  var body = "Hello, "+"\n\n"+"Please remember the below:";
  for (var i = 1; i < lr; i++) {
    if (val[i][2] == compare) {
      var bodyVal = val[i][0];
      body = body+"\n - "+bodyVal;
      match = true;
      Logger.log(body);
    }
  }
  if(match) {
    MailApp.sendEmail({
      to: "mail@example.com",
      subject: "Reminder",
      body: body
    });
  }
}
```

I hope this helps someone who may be looking for the same thing :)

Answer (score 0):

**Send email once a month**

```
function sendChangeDetailsEmail() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName("BALANCE SHEET");
  var dt=new Date();
  var today=dt.getDate();
  var days=new Date(dt.getFullYear(),dt.getMonth()+1,0).getDate();//number of days in this month
  var emailDay=sh.getRange('M3').getValue();
  if(emailDay>0 && emailDay<=Days && emailDay==today) {
    var data1 = sh.getRange("G2").getValue(); 
    var emailRange = ss.getSheetByName("BALANCE SHEET").getRange("G2"); 
    var emailRange1 = ss.getSheetByName("BALANCE SHEET").getRange("G1"); 
    var emailAddress = emailRange.getValue();
    var recipient = emailRange1.getValue();
    var message = 'Hello ' + recipient + "\r\r" + 'Please see the current amount that needs paying off: ' + data1 + "\r\r" + 'Many Thanks';
    var subject = 'REMINDER - Amount Due';
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
  }
}
```

Run the next function just once and check Edit/Current Project Trigger to make sure that there is one and only one trigger created.

```
function createSendChangeDetailsEmail() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('sendChangeDetailsEmail').timeBased().everyDays(1).atHour(6).create();
}
```